# ImageResizer SQLReader Plugin Retrieve ContentType

Tags: imageresizer

I saw in the flaws.txt on GitHub that the SQLReader currently lacks any mechanism to retrieve the ContentType from the database.

My database lets users store various types of images and files in the DB and the content type is always stored with the file.

I'm interested in trying to resolve this, but am kind of not sure where to start.  I've worked my way through the existing SQLReader and BlobProviderBase but can't seem to find a way to even pass the content type back up the chain.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you *really* need extension-less images? The easy solution is to use extensions that match the content-types when generating URLs for the front-end.

Comment: Because to do so on front end would require a good many additional database calls to retrieve the content type just to pass it to my image server which already has to lookup the image to get it out of the database and can get its content type at the same time.

Comment: You're not listing the images out of the database to start with (such that an extra column or sproc could fix)? 

This is not currently easy to implement, as we require content-type to be known before any expensive calls happen (or disk caching is a bust).